# Difference between fetch and postman's results

Tags: flask, cookies, axios, fetch-api, samesite

I have a simple login backend which has two routes login and get_user. After a user is logged in, a cookie is set such that it enables other routes like get_user. I tested this backend with Postman and after correct login, the cookie is set and get_user responds with user's data.

However, when I try to use fetch or axios in React and JS, I get problems. After I fetch login, I can see the cookie is sent, however, fetch get_user acts like cookie is not set at all.

I provided a minimal example to show that server side session somehow doesn't work with fetch:

**Frontend**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Set value: </h1> <h2 id="set_value"></h2>
<h1> Get value: </h1> <h2 id="get_value"></h2>

</body>
<script>
    // ..\..\Flask_general_framework\backend\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
    async function Set_user_fetch()
    {
        // Get user        
        let user = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/set/gggg', {
            'method': 'GET',
            //credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS},
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name',
            }
        })
        user = await user.json();
        console.log("await user:", user);
        document.getElementById("set_value").innerHTML = user.value;
    }

    async function Get_user_fetch()
    {                
        let user = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get', {
            'method': 'GET',
            //credentials: 'include',
            credentials: "same-origin",
            mode: 'cors',            
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS},
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name',
         }
        })
        user = await user.json();        
        console.log("await user:", user);
        document.getElementById("get_value").innerHTML = user.value;
    }    

    Set_user_fetch().then( () => {
        Get_user_fetch();
    });
    
</script>
</html>
```

**Backend:**

```py
from re import I
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from flask_cors import CORS
import redis

import datetime as dt
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super secret key'
#app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
#app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] =  redis.from_url('redis://localhost:9876')
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = dt.timedelta(days=7).total_seconds()
server_session = Session()     
server_session.init_app(app)

@app.route('/set/<value>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def set_value(value):
    session['value'] = value
    return {"value": value}

@app.route('/get', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_value():
    return {"value": session.get('value', 'None')}

app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Server Side

In order to support cross-site cookies in modern browsers, you need to configure your server to use the `Set-Cookie` attribute `SameSite=None` (see [Flask-specific example here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/python-flask.md)). Unfortunately, this also requires the `Secure` attribute and an `HTTPS` enabled server.

For local development, you can get around this by serving your client and server on the same hostname, eg `localhost` with `SameSite=Lax` (or omitting `SameSite` which defaults to "Lax").

By *"same hostname"* I mean that if your frontend code makes requests to `localhost:5000`, you should open it in your browser at `http://localhost:<frontend-port>`. Similarly, if you make requests to `127.0.0.1:5000`, you should open it at `http://127.0.0.1:<frontend-port>`.

Lax same-site restrictions don't come into play if only the ports differ.

### Client Side

You have a few problems here...

1. You're sending headers in your request that do not belong there. `Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers that must come from the server.
2. You set `credentials` to `same-origin` but are sending a request to a different host. To use cookies, you need to set `credentials` to `"include"`. See [Request.credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials).
3. You have no error handling for non-successful requests.

You're also setting a lot of redundant properties and headers and can trim down your code significantly.

```js
async function Set_user_fetch() {
  const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/set/gggg", {
    credentials: "include",
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
  }

  const user = await res.json();
  console.log("await user:", user);
  document.getElementById("set_value").innerHTML = user.value;
}

async function Get_user_fetch() {                
  const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get", {
    credentials: "include",
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
  }

  const user = await res.json();        
  console.log("await user:", user);
  document.getElementById("get_value").innerHTML = user.value;
}
```

If you were using Axios, you would set the `withCredentials` config to `true`

```js
axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/set/gggg", {
  withCredentials: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and the code, however using your code, I am still getting this: [Set value: gggg, Get value: None]. Do you get something else?

Comment: Both set and get have set-cookie in response headers, but not in request header. And the value of session inside the cookie looks different between set and get. If I try with postman, it works fine. I shared flask code, in case the issue is in backend [unlikely since postman works].

Comment: @roy I added the section at the top around server-side configuration and a workaround for local development 

Comment: Thanks, I just saw it, I tried to use 127.0.01 for both frontend and backend but the same issue.

Comment: @Roy as in you're opening your browser at `http://127.0.0.1:<some port>`?

Comment: yes, I run flask like this: app.run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True) or app.run(host='127:0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True) and postman can set and get correctly.

Comment: @Roy that's not what I asked you. What URL do you open in your browser for the frontend app?

Comment: There is no frontend, It is just an html file that has script tag with fetch commands and shows the response.

Comment: @Roy You can't make cross-site requests from a `file:///` URL. It needs to be served via a proper HTTP server. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used a http server and you are right, it works. This helped me a lot. Thanks