# Javascript Fetch not sending JWT httponly cookie to .Net Core 6 API

Tags: javascript, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, session-cookies, fetch-api

I've been working on implementing JWT and refresh_tokens. The latest attempt uses refresh_tokens stored in an httpOnly cookie. My API is a .Net Core 6 API, and using Swagger and Postman, things seem to work fine. I see the refresh_token cookie in the browser devtools Application Tab. In Swagger and Postman, when I run my refresh_token endpoint, which uses the httpContextAccessor to get the Request.Cookies, it's fine. I see in the Request Headers, a cookie with my refresh_token.
Now, my attempts to replicate this work in VSCode running a live server is where I'm running into trouble. I'm using a vanilla JS front end and Fetch. My login code works fine:

```
fetch(loginUrl, {
   method: "POST",
   credentials: "include",
   body: JSON.stringify(authBody),
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

The Browser dev tools shows my cookie is fine.
My attempts to call my refresh_token endpoint however does NOT send the cookie.
I don't see a cookie in the Request Headers. I've been trying some variations of the above fetch code but the cookie won't go.
Now the only thing I can think of is a cors issue...
My API is running from VS2022 and is at https://localhost:7121 and my VSCode Live Server is http://localhost:5500.

On the API side, I've tried setting the cookie with:

```
HttpOnly = true,
Secure = true,
Expires = expireTime,
```

I've tried including some variations of SameSite too, but not much luck.
Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what path is the cookie set to?

Comment: i didn't specify, but in the devtools it shows "/"

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like I got the cookie to work... it seems the "SameSite" property for the cookie was messing it up. I just noticed a checkbox in the Network tab in the Devtools that showed filtered out request cookies, and it indicated SameSite being strict was preventing the cookie from going.
I set it to none in my API, and it looks like the cookie is sent now... the only issue now is the response I get back is opaque, so I don't get my new tokens from the API.

Comment: So it turns out my opaque response was due to my trying to do a fetch mode of no-cors... this was from my previous attempt to see if that made any difference... So, now it seems to be ok... My only concern is if SameSite None is going to raise any security flags... Hopefully this little endeavor helps anyone else who runs into this.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919232/283366) regarding cross-origin requests with cookies and `localhost` development