# Keeping HttpSession in Spring Boot server while fetching data in Reactjs via API

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, session

Im new to spring boot and reactjs
I have my spring boot rest api running at localhost:8080/api and a react app consuming this api at localhost:3000.
In my Spring Boot app. I using HttpSession to keep the session for each user
my userController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private static final String ADMIN_ROLE = "ADMIN";
    private static final String SUCCESSMSG = "Success";
    private static final String FAILMSG = "Fail";
    private static final String UNAUTHORIZED = "Unauthorized";

    @Autowired
    public UserController(HttpSession session, UserService userService) {
        this.session = session;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> deactivateUser(@RequestParam("email") String target) {
        try {
            User sessionUser = (User) session.getAttribute("user"); /* Session user */
            if (sessionUser == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("session user information not found");
            }
            if (sessionUser.getEmail().compareToIgnoreCase(target) != 0
                    && sessionUser.getRoleId().compareToIgnoreCase(ADMIN_ROLE) != 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            userService.deactivate(target);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
                    new ResponseObject(SUCCESSMSG, "deactive account successfully", target));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(
                    new ResponseObject(FAILMSG, "Failed deactive account: "
                            + target, e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public User showCurrentUser() {
        return (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    }

    @GetMapping("/profile")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> getUserProfile(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        try {
            User sessionUser = (User) session.getAttribute("user"); /* Session user */
            if (sessionUser.getEmail().compareToIgnoreCase(email) != 0
                    && sessionUser.getRoleId().compareToIgnoreCase(ADMIN_ROLE) != 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            List<User> users = userService.findByEmail(email);
            if (!users.isEmpty()) {
                User user = users.get(0);
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
                        new ResponseObject(SUCCESSMSG, "Get user profile success", user));
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(
                        new ResponseObject(FAILMSG, "User not found", null));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(
                    new ResponseObject(FAILMSG, "Failed to retrieve user profile: " + e.getMessage(), null));
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/profile")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> updateUserProfile(@RequestBody User updatedUser) {
        try {
            User sessionUser = (User) session.getAttribute("user"); /* Session user */
            /* check if updated user is match with session user or session user is admin */
            if (sessionUser.getEmail().compareToIgnoreCase(updatedUser.getEmail()) != 0
                    && sessionUser.getRoleId().compareToIgnoreCase(ADMIN_ROLE) != 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            userService.save(updatedUser);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
                    new ResponseObject(SUCCESSMSG, "update user profile successfully", updatedUser));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(
                    new ResponseObject(FAILMSG, "can not update user profile", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    /* only admin can use this api to show User list */
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> showAll() {
        try {
            User sessionUser = (User) session.getAttribute("user"); /* Session user */
            if (sessionUser.getRoleId().equals(ADMIN_ROLE)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
                    new ResponseObject(SUCCESSMSG, "retrieve users information ", userService.showUsers()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(
                    new ResponseObject(FAILMSG, "can not retrieves user information", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    /* Create new user account based on json sent by client site */
    @PostMapping("/login")
    ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> userLogin(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        try {
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            List<User> u1 = userService.findByEmail(loginRequest.getEmail().trim());
            if (u1.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("can not find email");
            }
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(loginRequest.getPassword(), u1.get(0).getPassword().trim())) {
                session.setAttribute("user", u1.get(0));
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
                        new ResponseObject(SUCCESSMSG, "Login Successful!", u1));
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("login failed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(
                    new ResponseObject(FAILMSG, "Email or PassWord invalid!",
                            e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    /* Invalidate current session */
    @PostMapping("/logout")
    ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> logout() {
        session.invalidate();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
                new ResponseObject(SUCCESSMSG, "Logout success!", null));
    }
```

in my Reactjs application, I using fetch to use data via api

```
const Current = async () =>{
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/user/current', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    }})
  .then(response => response.json)
  .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
const SignIn = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    const requestBody = {
      email: data.get("email"),
      password: data.get("password"),
    };
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/user/login", {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: 'include',  // Include session cookies
        headers: {
          "content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const responseData = await response.json();
        console.log(responseData);
        setErrorMessage("");
        Current();
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      } else {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        setErrorMessage(errorData.message);
        passwordRef.current.value = "";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error:", error.message);
    }
  };
```

my properties file:

```
#connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_learninghub
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345678
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#no permission to change database via hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#create connection to database
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#for session handle
spring.session.store-type=redis 
spring.data.redis.host=localhost
spring.data.redis.port=6379

#define the maximum interval,for which an idle session can remain active before it expires.
server.servlet.session.timeout=30m
security.basic.enabled=false
```

the problem is, after my login API was called and successful. it seems that in the second call (.../current), my HttpSession inside Spring Boot app was losing and I can not get any data. I understand that using JWT is a better way to resolve this problem but I'm not sure if is there any way to keep my HttpSession in spring boot after every time I use API in react js application.
thanks in advance

Im try using CorsConfig to fix that problem in spring boot but it seems it not work

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the same host for both client and server (ie pick one of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`) and you'll be able to use `SameSite=Lax` in your cookie configuration. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919232/283366)

Comment: I tried to set all url to localhost like you said and in properties file I add this code:
`server.reactive.session.cookie.same-site=lax` . however, I caught this issue: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy. @Phil is on strike

Comment: What's the rest of that error message? Why was it blocked?

Comment: when I use CorsConfig above, the message error will print
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.